# Regular expression for positive number with 2 decimals used for displaying money

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regular expression for displaying numbers with 2 decimals for displaying money of various currencies in the world. This regex should only allow 1 dot or comma as a decimal separator. And only allow positive numbers and the numbers can't begin with a 0.

Goals:

- Both dot and comma can be used as a decimal separator
- The decimal separator can only be once in a number
- Numbers can't begin with a zero
- Only positive numbers allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

My solution for this dilemma is the following:

```
^\d*[,.]\d{2}?$
```

Beware that this is the official regex solution, for Java this works:

```
^\\d*([,.]\\d{0,2})?$
```

Java automatically helps you if you set the `DecimalFormatSymbols`
Use `setDecimalSeparator` and `setGroupingSeparator` to set the decimal separator and the grouping separator.

### Explanation

This: `^\\d*` tells regex that a number needs to start with 0 to 9 and can be repeated 0 or more times.

This: `[,.]` tells regex that the next thing needs to be a dot or a comma

This: `\\d{2}?$` tell regex that a number needs to start with 0 to 9 and needs to match exactly 2 times and that it's optional. The `$` asserts this or checks it at the end of the line.

`()` grouping in regex.

### Verification

https://regex101.com/r/tbdvrk/3

### Regex for negative and positive decimals

```
^-?\\d*([,.]\\d{0,2})?$
```

### Regex for integer

```
^[1-9]\d*$
```

This is with a condition for allowing nothing:

```
^$|^[1-9]\d*$
```

`|` means: *OR* and `^$` means: *nothing*, therefore `^$|` means: *nothing OR something else*.

### Regex for negative and positive integers

```
^$|^[-1-9]\d*$
```